# Writing a complex SQL query, with table relations

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I will present my table structures first (only relevant fields will be mentioned)

```
/* The table Users */

user_id | user_name | user_registration_date
1       | USER1     | 19/09/2010
2       | USER2     | 20/09/2010


/* The table Levels_Completed */

user_id | level_id
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 1
```

I would like to display a scoreboard. The first user on the list, will be the one with the highest count of levels he completed.
For the example above, USER1 will be displayed above USER2.

I want to receive the next data:

```
user_id, user_name, user_registration_date, COUNT(level_id rows) AS score
```

Ordered by the count of score, for each SQL row I receive.
Example:

```
1 | USER1 | 19/09/2010 | 2
2 | USER2 | 20/09/2010 | 1
```

I know how to use `INNER JOIN`, but I think the counting and ordering are above my current level. Help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Users.user_id, user_name, user_registration_date, COUNT(level_id) AS score
FROM Users INNER JOIN Levels_Completed ON Users.user_id = Levels_Completed.user_id
GROUP BY Users.user_id, user_name, user_registration_date
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you explain why did you use `MIN` on the date, and also `GROUP BY` on the id and name?

Comment: The `GROUP BY` is to tell SQL which columns need to be considered "same" so it aggregates over your COUNT(), SUM(), MAX() etc. columns. That is, it takes all of the columns which are _grouped by_ and for every same values (across all columns in that list) it aggregates your requested field. Regarding the `MIN` - in this case it's my mistake (and I will now update my answer) but imagine this is a different date for every record, say the date in which the user played, per game. You don't want SQL to consider different dates as different grouping, so you just pick one (for example by using `MIN`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   U.user_id,
   U.user_name,
   U.user_registration_date,
   COUNT(L.level_id) as score
FROM Users U
   LEFT JOIN Levels_Completed L
       ON U.User_Id = L.User_Id
GROUP BY U.user_id, U.user_name, U.user_registration_date
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Users.user_id, user_name, user_registration_date, score
FROM Users
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, COUNT(level_id) AS score
  FROM Levels_Completed
  GROUP BY user_id)
USING (user_id)
ORDER BY score DESC
```